# Reading Data From Another Application

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, ole

How do I read data from another window's application?

The other application has a TG70.ApexGridOleDB32 according to Spy++.  It has 3 columns and a few rows.  I need to read this data from another application I am writing.  Can someone help me?

I am writing the code in MFC/C++

Comment: What are you writing this in?

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems donot allow directly reading data from different applications/processes. In case your "application" is a sub-process of main application, you can use shared objects to pass data to and fro.

However, in your case, it seems like the most appropriate would be to dump your data on disk. Suppose you have applications A and B. So B can generate the data and push this data onto a regular file or a database. Then A can access the file/database to proceed. Note that this will be a very costly implementation because of sheer number of I/Os performed.

So if your application is generating a lot of data, making both the applications as threads would be the way to go.